# Querying a MongoDB collection with documents containing an array of (sub)documents where ALL documents in the array match a condition

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Say you have a mongoDB collection called comments that contains documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55fc4e8f2b21ff102bb20d94"),
    "userName" : "user0053",
    "comment" : [ 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-09-18T17:49:03.678Z"),
            "title" : "Some title XYZ",
            "status" : "Approved",
            "content" : "blah blah blah"
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-09-18T17:49:03.678Z"),
            "title" : "Some nice looking title",
            "status" : "Approved",
            "content" : "blah blah blah"
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-09-18T17:49:03.678Z"),
            "title" : "A title",
            "status" : "Spam",
            "content" : "blah blah blah"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `comment` element is an array of documents, each containing several elements, among those a status with 3 (or any) possible values, say *Approved*, *Spam*, *PendingReview*.

I want to query all the documents in the collection whose comment element contains an array in which ALL documents have a status of say "*Approved*".

In the example above, the document does not qualify because there is at least one comment element that has a status different to Approved.

I believe this cannot be done with the $all and $elemMatch options, but it would need to be done with an Aggregate pipeline.  I just haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: At it's simplest form, this could be achieved with `$nin` I think:  `db.collection.find({"comment.status" : {$nin : ["Spam" , "PendingReview"]}})`

Comment: Wow... that simple!   Thank you so much, it actually works..      If you are intersted, please create an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At it's simplest form, this can be achieved with [$nin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/).

`db.collection.find({"comment.status" : {$nin : ["Spam" , "PendingReview"]}})`